# An integral involve Guassian Hypergeomstric function.

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

In handling the following integral:
$$I = \int_0^1 {{u^{{m_2} - 1}}{{\left( {1 - u} \right)}^{{m_3} - 1}}{}_2{F_1}\left( {{m_1} + {m_2} + {m_3},{m_2} + {m_3};{m_2} + {m_3} + 1;\left( {q - p} \right)u - q} \right)} du$$
Where all of the parameters are real and positive value, and ${}_2{F_1}\left( {} \right)$ is the Guassian Hypergeomstric function.
We decide to use these formula:
(1)
$$\int_0^y {{x^{\alpha  - 1}}{{\left( {y - x} \right)}^{\beta  - 1}}{}_2{F_1}} \left( {a,b;c; - \omega x} \right)dx,[y,Re{\text{ }}\alpha {\text{,Re }}\beta {\text{ > 0;}}\left| {{\text{arg}}\left( {1 + \omega y} \right)} \right| < \pi ]$$
(2)
$$\eqalign{
  & \int_0^y {{x^{\alpha  - 1}}{{\left( {y - x} \right)}^{\beta  - 1}}{}_2{F_1}} \left( {a,b;c;1 - \omega x} \right)dx,  \cr 
  & [y,\operatorname{Re} {\text{ }}\alpha ,\operatorname{Re} {\text{ }}\beta  > 0,\operatorname{Re} \left( {c - a - b + \alpha } \right) > 0;\left| {\arg \left( \omega  \right)} \right| < \pi ] \cr} $$
But we failed to find the relationship between ${}_2{F_1}\left( {a,b;c;kx + b} \right)$ and ${}_2{F_1}\left( {a,b;c;1 - \omega x} \right),{}_2{F_1}\left( {a,b;c; - \omega x} \right)$, So, is this method really works? Or any other method can work out this integral? Or any approximate method to this problem? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{0}^{1} t^{\mu-1} (1-t)^{\nu -1} {}_{2}F_{1}(\lambda+\mu+\nu, \mu+\nu; \mu+\nu+1; (q-p)t-q) dt.
\end{align}
Expand the hypergeometric function into series form to obtain
\begin{align}
I &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n} (\mu+\nu)_{n} }{n! (\mu+\nu+1)_{n} }
\cdot \int_{0}^{1} t^{\mu-1} (1-t)^{\nu -1} (-q + (q-p)t)^{n} dt \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n} (\mu+\nu)_{n} (-q)^{n}}{n! (\mu+\nu+1)_{n} }
\cdot \int_{0}^{1} t^{\mu-1} (1-t)^{\nu -1} (1 - \frac{(q-p)}{q} t)^{n} dt.
\end{align}
The remaining integral can be quickly determined by use of the hypergeometric definition
\begin{align}
B(\beta, \gamma - \beta) \ {}_{2}F_{1}(\alpha, \beta; \gamma; z) = \int_{0}^{1} t^{\beta -1}
(1-t)^{\gamma - \beta -1} (1-z t)^{- \alpha} dt
\end{align}
which is then seen to be
\begin{align}
I &= B(\mu, \nu) \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n} (\mu+\nu)_{n} (-q)^{n}}{n! 
(\mu+\nu+1)_{n} } \ {}_{2}F_{1}(-n, \mu; \nu-\mu; \frac{q-p}{q}).
\end{align}
Again, expanding the hypergeometric series yields
\begin{align}
I &= B(\mu, \nu) \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n} 
(\mu+\nu)_{n} (-n)_{k} (\mu)_{k}  (-q)^{n}}{n! k! (\mu+\nu+1)_{n} (\nu-\mu)_{k}} \left(\frac{q-p}{q}
\right)^{k} \\
&= B(\mu,\nu) \ \sum_{n,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n+k} 
(\mu+\nu)_{n+k} (-n-k)_{k} (\mu)_{k} }{ (\mu+\nu+1)_{n+k} (\nu-\mu)_{k}} \cdot \frac{(-q)^{n+k}}{(n+k)!}
\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{q-p}{q}\right)^{k}}{k!} \\
&= B(\mu,\nu) \ \sum_{n,k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda+\mu+\nu)_{n+k} 
(\mu+\nu)_{n+k} (\mu)_{k} }{ (\mu+\nu+1)_{n+k} (\nu-\mu)_{k}} \cdot \frac{(-q)^{n}}{n!}
\cdot \frac{(q-p)^{k}}{k!} \\
&= B(\mu,\nu) \ F_{1:0,1}^{2:0,1} \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \lambda+\mu+\nu, \mu+\nu:
-; \mu; \\ \mu+\nu+1: -; \nu-\mu; \end{array} \ -q, q-p \right]
\end{align}
where the resulting expression is a Kampe de Feriet function.

Hence,
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{1} t^{\mu-1} (1-t)^{\nu -1} {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \lambda+\mu+\nu, \mu+\nu; \\
\mu+\nu+1; \end{array} \ (q-p)t-q \right) \ dt \\
&= B(\mu,\nu) \ F_{1:0,1}^{2:0,1} \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \lambda+\mu+\nu, \mu+\nu:
-; \mu; \\ \mu+\nu+1: -; \nu-\mu; \end{array} \ -q, q-p \right].
\end{align}

The Kamp\'{e} de Feriet function is given by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function .

Comment: Thanks very much,looks wonderful,but what's the short line in Kampe de Feriet function stands for? INF or NULL or others?

Comment: @Chaoqing "--" means that no element is in that position. For example \begin{align} {}_{1}F_{0}(a;-; x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{n}}{n!} \ x^{n} \end{align}

Comment: oh,get it,that's what i mean "NULL",thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,but i didn't find the Kampe de Feriet function in matlab(my matlab version is 2013b),is there any sofeware which can plot the function easily?